# How can I unlock my encrypted locker (with the FLKA file extension) if I forgot the locker password, but have the master password?

Tags: windows, passwords, encryption

I am using [Folder Lock 7.2](http://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/) on Windows 7.

I have the master password, but I forgot the locker password.
I tried all the passwords which I usually use as a password, but they're all useless. I'm looking for a way to unlock the folder, as it contains my personal pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck according to the FAQ for Folder Lock.

> Please note that since we DO NOT store any passwords, your password CANNOT be retrieved. Please make sure that you REMEMBER YOUR LOCKER PASSWORD AT ALL TIMES!

*[Folder Lock FAQ](http://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/faq), encryption section, question 7.*

In other words, **you cannot retrieve the contents of your locker if you've lost the password**.